How to make environment variables private with Next.js apps hosted on Firebase App Hosting
I'm talking about Firebase App Hosting. Not Firebase Hosting.

Inside apphosting.yaml, I reference secrets managed by Google Secret Manager.
If I simply do this:
env:
  - variable: MY_SECRET
    secret: MY_SECRET

MY_SECRET can be sent to browsers.
If I specify the availability to BUILD only like this:
env:
  - variable: MY_SECRET
    secret: MY_SECRET
    availability:
      - BUILD

Then the pages will 500 because I access process.env.MY_SECRET in server components.
Testing the NEXT_PUBLIC_ prefix yielded strange behaviors.
Consider this apphosting.yaml file:
env:
  - variable: NEXT_PUBLIC_MY_SECRET
    secret: MY_SECRET
  - variable: MY_SECRET
    secret: MY_SECRET

The NEXT_PUBLIC_MY_SECRET variable is accessible on both server and client components (marked with "use client"). As expected.
But the MY_SECRET variable has two problems:

It can be put in the HTML via a server component
Inside the client component, it is only removed after Next.js hydrates (sic)

So what am I missing here?
How can we set an environment variable so that it is available to Next.js when it receives requests but won't ever be sent to browsers?
Thanks!
